# filtering by pipe: Template parse Error Angular4

Tags: json, angular, typescript, pipe, filtering

its my first time with "pipe" so I think I missed few things:
I have a JSON file which contain data of products. the products can be sort by "ProductTags" - JSON with the tag they can be filter by. also, I have JSON Which contain details about the filter:

```
"PriceFilter": [
{
    "TagId": 20,
    "Type": "Budget",
    "Value": 5,
    "Values": null,
    "DisplayText": "$5",
    "Order": null
},
{
    "TagId": 21,
    "Type": "Budget",
    "Value": 10,
    "Values": null,
    "DisplayText": "$10",
    "Order": null
}]
```

product:

```
"Products": [
{
    "ProductId": 206419,
    "ProductTitle": "Mom is Fabulous Fruit Box - Good",
    "ProductTags": [ 20, 2, 3, 4 ]
}]
```

I need to order the products using the tags in this way: [price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqk7f.png)

store. html

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let P of PriceFilter | filter : term | orderBy: 'Price'">
        <td>{{PriceFilter.DisplayText}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

store component:

```
stores=[];
products=[];

PriceFilter = [];
GenderFilter =[];
filtered=[];
constructor(private _storeService:StoreService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getProducts()
       .subscribe(data =>{
           this.products = data.Stores.Products;
           this.stores=data.Stores;
           this.PriceFilter = data.PriceFilter;
           this.GenderFilter = data.GenderFilter;
           console.log(data.PriceFilter)
           console.log(data.GenderFilter)
           console.log(data.Stores)
       });     
}
```

filter pipe:

```
transform(items: any[], term): any {
    console.log('term', term);

    return term 
        ? items.filter(item => item.ProductTags.indexOf(term) !== -1)
        : items;
}
```

orderBy pipe:

```
export class OrderbyPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(items: any[], orderBy: string): any {
    console.log('orderdBy', orderBy);

    return items.sort((a, b) => {return b[orderBy] - a[orderBy]});
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the official Angular guides suggest **not** to use pipes for `sorting` / `filtering`, as they will be called on each change detection, and it becomes a waste of resources https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: @user184994 can you suggest different way? Thank you

Comment: Just filter the data within your component TS file

Comment: @user184994 example? All I read with angular is with pipe..I need to see how diffrently

Comment: The code will be exactly the same. You can copy it out of your pipe, and into the relevant component. Then, any time your list data changes, or your filter changes, execute that code.

Comment: with event emitter? @user184994

Comment: With what event emitter?

Comment: EventEmitter @user184994

Comment: I know what an EventEmitter is, but I don't know what you're asking

Comment: @user184994you said "Then, any time your list data changes" how should I knot it changes

Comment: I don't know your application, so I don't know where the filters can be changed from.

Comment: @user184994 I wrote above. if not, How you knew to advice?

Comment: Because regardless of where your filters are being set, the official angular recommendation is don't use `pipe`s for it.